# What is the difference between gcc test.c -L. -lft and gcc test.c libft.a?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, static-libraries

I have a static library with the filename "libft.a" and a .c file with the main called "test.c".

How do these two commands differ from each other?

```
gcc test.c -L. -lft
gcc test.c libft.a
```

Both commands compile well, and the binary file produces the expected output.

Is the first command more specific about linking static / dynamic libraries?
Can the easier syntax cause unexpected behavior with libraries?

I also have a libft.h file that is related; it's included in test.c with

```
#include "./includes/libft.h"
```

And the object files (that are put into the static library and indexed) are created with

```
gcc -c src1.c src2.c src3.c -Iincludes
```

The general file structure looks like this:

```
libft.a
test.c
includes/
├─ libft.h
srcs/
├─ src1.c
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll use the simpler command then, and remember to be explicit.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case the result could be different if some shared library `libft.so` (or equivalent) exists. With `gcc test.c -L. -lft` you explicitly tell the linker to search for both shared and static libraries in the current directory; when run it finds a static `libft.a`, so it will link against the compiled `test.c` and `libft.a`.  However, if `libft.a` was missing in the current directory (not built yet?), then this would look for other libraries called `libfta.so` or `libft.a` in other directories on its standard search list.

The second command explicitly links the compiled `test.c` and `libft.a`, both in the working directory, and produces the same result as the first command if there was no shared `libft` in the current directory or the standard library path.